# Duplicate key (attempted merging values x and x)

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a simple class:

```
public class Rule {
    int id;
    long cableType;
}
```

I want to convert a list with objects of this class to `Map<Integer, Long>`, so I wrote code:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = ruleList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Rule::getId, Rule::getCableType));
```

The list has a duplication like `(1, 10), (1,40)` and when I'm running this code I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 21 (attempted merging values 31 and 30)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You cannot have two different values mapped to the same key in a simple `Map`.

Comment: I believe that it will need a pre-process. But what do YOU want to do with the duplicated value? sum the cableType, keep the first one , keep the last, ...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To avoid this error, you need to take one of the duplicate entries for example, to do this you need:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Rule::getId, Rule::getCableType, (r1, r2) -> r1));
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't knew the collector could take a lambda to fix duplicate keys

Comment: API Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth noting that prior to the `.collect` you may want to consider a `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(rule -> rule.cableType))` or something like that, so that way you can be intentional about which values are kept in a duplicate key situation.

The answer from @Youcef above surely gets rid of the exception, but the value selected for the duplicate key is based on whatever order the list is in currently.

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is already solved but i just found out of this cool `.distinct()` operator.

so my suggestion is to use:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = ruleList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Rule::getId, Rule::getCableType));
```

Comment: How to distinguish different Rule object? Aren\`t they all unique for data like OP offered `(1, 10), (1,40)`? So I don\`t think this will work.